# Complementation according to Quirk et al.: syntactic concept vs. semantic concept

Tags: grammar, semantics, complements, grammatical-roles, functions

According to the definition of "complementation" in "The Oxford Dictionary of English Grammar", for most linguists complementation is a syntactic concept. However, the definition also notes a semantic perspective in the following quotation from "A Comprehensive Grammar of the English Language" by Quirk et al.:

> We reserve the term COMPLEMENTATION (as distinct from complement) for
> the function of a part of a phrase or clause which follows a word, and
> completes the specification of a meaning relationship which that word
> implies. As such, complementation may be either obligatory or optional
> on the syntactic level.

In the above quotation, as far as I understand, Quirk et al. mix two different things:

1. A semantic concept: We reserve the term COMPLEMENTATION for the function of a part of a phrase or clause which follows a word, and completes the meaning which that word implies.
2. A syntactic concept: complementation may be either obligatory or optional on the syntactic level.

**Question: Do Quirk et al. mean by "function" in the above quotation a pure syntactic function or a semantic concept / function? Or in other words, do Quirk et al. define complementation as a pure semantic concept / function?**

Comment: Complements are distinct in that they must be licensed by the head. That's what sets them apart from adjuncts.

Comment: Obligatory elements are always complements: they are needed to complete the verb phrase; optional elements may be either complements or adjuncts.

Comment: It seems to me that *...completes the specification of a meaning **relationship** which that word* implies Quirk et al. are defining ***complementation*** as a purely ***syntactic*** designation. Which is sometimes ***optional*** - as often happens with certain prepositions in certain contexts, where the entire "complement" may be essential to the *meaning* of an utterance, but the preposition introducing that complement doesn't always carry any meaning itself (it''s just syntactically required or optional).

Comment: Matthews in _The Concise Oxford Dictionary of Linguistics_ defines it as ‘A syntactic element seen as completing the construction of another element’: (the syntactic concept construction is preferable to the semantic concept meaning). He goes on to say, more specifically, that it applies to elements which are within the valency of a verb or other lexical unit. And his entry for ‘valency’ is: ‘The range of syntactic elements either required or specifically permitted by a verb or other lexical unit’ – which is equivalent to licensing.

Comment: There are (surprise!) varying usages among linguists. I use the term _complement_, for instance, **only** to refer to a type of subordinate clause that is subject or object. That's strictly syntactic. The usage that Quirk et al refer to is a much older one; it used to be thought that sentences could be "completed" by using the "appropriate" words, and you would know which were appropriate if you were appropriately educated. That's not even semantics, that's handwaving.

Comment: Complements may be clauses or phrases, providing they are licensed by the head. 'Licensing' is the key word here; it's what distinguishes complements from adjuncts and other modifiers.

Comment: @BillJ You provide a definition of "complement" as a pure syntactic function. But it does not answer my question: Do Quirk et al. consider complementation as a pure syntactic function or a semantic function? By the way, if I use your definition of complement as a syntactic function, could you provide an example for an optional complement?

Comment: They use the term 'function', which is a syntactic one, but their definition seems largely based on semantics. Frankly, it's 'fuzzy', which is why I prefer the syntactic one, where a complement must be licensed by the head. Examples of optional complements include: "She read (the report)" /"He ate the steak (almost raw)" and the predicatives in "They departed (content)" / "He washed it (clean)".

Comment: The problem is the licensing arrangement. Licenses are imaginary things that can't be detected; they hafta be argued for in terms of things that **can** be detected. Thus, tests are in order. We got lots of examples, but what are the tests?

Comment: Matthew's definition (the equivalent of licensing) is fine. I don't see any problems with understanding it.